# Tableau multiple connections type of data change

Tags: connection, tableau-desktop, abstract-data-type

I am stuck on Tableau trying to put together tables. When joining tables under multiple connections in Tableau, I tried to change the type of data in 2 tables, but after changing it in one it shows me a red line on the joining symbol that doesn't let me change it on the other table, how can I go back to the columns to change the type of data on both?

I changed the type of data on one table and immediately it took me back to connections showing me a red line on one side of the connection, not letting me change the type of data on the other table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing the Coursera's course and I found the same issues. The only thing you have to do is to expand the left down area that have columns like "Type, FIeld Name, Physical table etc. Then you will be able to see the the the field you want to convert to other type. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t43N1.png)